# Rails validate with specific format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How to validate field with specific format

i want to validate

```
validates_format_of :ga_profile_id, with: 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x'
```

i need to validate this format`UA-xxxxxxxx-x`

but i get an errors

`A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :with`

Comment: What format you want to validate ?

Comment: @Vishal `'UA-xxxxxxxx-x'` this one

Comment: Like ga_profile_id should start with "UA" then "-" should come then 8 characters string then "-" should come and last character . like this ?

Comment: The error explains what needs to happen here. It explains that you need to pass either a proc, lambda, or for your case relevant, a regular expression. [The Official Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_format_of) is quite good here, actually.

Answer (score 0):

That means you need to pass `with: /YourRegularExpressionHere/`

Comment: For example: `/UA-[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}/`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like this

```
validates :ga_profile_id format: { with: /UA-xxxxxxxx-x/ }
```